# How to fix "Non-existing setting" error from robotframework and seleniumlibrary?

Tags: selenium, testing, automated-tests, robotframework

I am trying to run a script to search for the keyword "mdh" and to show mdh.se as a result.
I installed robot framework and selenium library and this is my script which I wrote in sublime text and saved as a .robot file.

```
*** Settings ***
Library Selenium2Library
Suite Setup Go to homepage
Suite Teardown Close All Browsers

*** Variables ***
${HOMEPAGE} http://www.google.com
${BROWSER} chrome

*** Test Cases ***
Google mdh and find mdh
Google and check results mdh www.mdh.se

*** Keywords ***
Google and check results
[Arguments] ${searchkey} ${result}
Input Text class_name=gLFyf gsfi ${searchkey}
Click Button class_name=Tg7LZd
Wait Until Page Contains ${result}
Go to homepage
Open Browser ${HOMEPAGE} ${BROWSER}
```

When I try to run the script with robot mdh.robot it says there are 5 errors.

```
C:\Users\malvi\Desktop>robot mdh.robot

[ ERROR ] Error in file 'C:\Users\malvi\Desktop\mdh.robot': Non-existing setting 'Library 
Selenium2Library'.

[ ERROR ] Error in file 'C:\Users\malvi\Desktop\mdh.robot': Non-existing setting 'Suite Setup Go to 
homepage'.

[ ERROR ] Error in file 'C:\Users\malvi\Desktop\mdh.robot': Non-existing setting 'Suite Teardown 
Close All Browsers'.

[ ERROR ] Error in file 'C:\Users\malvi\Desktop\mdh.robot': Setting variable '${HOMEPAGE} 
http://www.google.com' failed: Invalid variable name '${HOMEPAGE} http://www.google.com'.

[ ERROR ] Error in file 'C:\Users\malvi\Desktop\mdh.robot': Setting variable '${BROWSER} chrome' 
failed: Invalid variable name '${BROWSER} chrome'.
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Read the error message closely, and take it literally. It is saying there is no setting named `Suite Setup Go to homepage`, which is a true statement. There is a setting named `Suite Setup`, however.

You need at least two spaces between a setting name and the setting value.

Comment: Thank you I finally figured it out. Now i have another problem where I need to search for something but the search field does not have a name or id. Do you know how I can do that with Xpath? I copied the xpath but I do not know how to write it in the above example

Comment: @MalvinaLatifaj: Please mark the answer as an accepted answer if it resolved your question. Please read the documentation: [When someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)